# Object Factory with limited base class

Tags: c++, objectfactory

I ran into a quandary last night while designing an object factory and thought I'd ask here for some guidance.

Essentially, my 'CameraFactory' returns pointers to classes based on available types such as 'FIXED' or 'FREE' (and more but I'll keep this example short). All of which inherit from CameraBase.
However, my problem is that because the CameraBase class has very limited implementation, the user needs to perform a `static_cast<typeOfCameraRequested*>(returned CameraBaseDerivative*);` on the returned pointer.

I feel that by forcing the user to 'remember' to static cast the result is bad practice (I'm not using raw pointers in the actual implementation btw). But by my understanding, the only other way to create a 'neat' factory implementation would be to include an interface to all members/methods of the derivative classes in CameraBase so that the derivatives can be easily called.

Please could someone shed some light on the best approach to this issue? Should I re-design my classes? If so, what should it look like? Generics?

Thanks!

Code to consider:

```
Class CameraBase {

protected:

 SomeDataMember mDataMember;
}

Class FreeCamera : public CameraBase {

public:

  void SomeFreeCameraSpecificMethod();
}

class StaticCamera: public CameraBase {

public:

  void SomeStaticCameraSpecificMethod();
}

Class CameraFactory {

public:

  static BaseCamera* createCamera(CameraTypeEnum _type) {

    switch (_type) {

      case FREE:
        return createFreeCamera();
        break;

      case STATIC:
        return createStaticCamera();
        break;
    }
  }
}

FreeCamera* freeCam = static_cast<FreeCamera*>(CameraFactory::createCamera(FREE));
```

Comment: Why do you have a factory in the first place? If the caller has to say `static_cast<FreeCamera*>(CameraFactory::createCamera(FREE))`, they might as well do `createFreeCamera()` directly.

Comment: I thought about this. I was concerned about, in the fullness of time when there are many camera types, having many functions to create them.

However, I also think that perhaps I am being over eager to implement every design pattern I can, and could just stick to individual methods.

This is why I asked on here :)

As a followup question then: If this is not the right circumstance to implement a factory, what would you consider to be the right circumstances?

Comment: turn your create camera into a templated method?  Since you a talking about them casting.. This seems to state that they know the class type the wish to receive. This would also eliminate your argument as well.  so createCamera<StaticCamera>() instead.  You don't need "individual" if there is a common initialization.

Comment: @Jonathan Then why have `createCamera` at all? You can just do `StaticCamera()` and put the logic in the constructor.

Comment: If there is common init of the camera, then this can be done in the factory. You could have pools... Object reuse... etc...  Types might not be mutually exclusive... In that a Static Camera may be a type of free camera... but the user may not need to know that...

Comment: @Jonathan - I agree, one of the reasons I wanted to have a factory was to make sure that the pointer was stored in a separate cameraManager class and destroyed appropriately.

Comment: I would also suggest using singleton class rather than static member.